# Alter DB2 table with existent records with a new not null default '' column

Tags: db2

what will happen with existent records with this new column, will they have default '' ?
or this is only applying for new records? is this a safe way? Appreciate your help, regards.

SQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable  ADD COLUMN newColumn VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you run below command -

```
ALTER TABLE mytable  ADD COLUMN newColumn VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

All the existing rows in the table will have the value as a single space in column newColumn, and for newly inserted rows, You can specify the value in insert statement.

Comment: thank you it was very helpful!